# Matlab 2D-array indexing contradiction between for loop and vectorised version

Tags: matlab, for-loop, indexing, vectorization

I know there's been lots of indexing question on here, but this one seems puzzling to me, hope someone's got a quick answer for me, will understand if this one gets deleted though. I've got a 2D a-by-b array x and want to get from another array y this :

```
for i=1:b        
x(:,i) = y( (i-1) * k+1 : (i-1) * k+a )
end
```

without a for loop, like this :

```
x(:,1:b) = y( (0:b-1) * k+1 : (0:b-1) * k+a )
```

but to no avail, I get

"Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch."

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does `k` correspond to?

Comment: it can be anything suitable, say a positive integer, 2 for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can just use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to create those linear indices and index into `y` to get the desired output like so -

```
x = y(bsxfun(@plus,[1:a]',[0:b-1]*k))
```

Comment: thanks. And what if I want to multiply element by element with another vector of length a? Could I integrate that in bsfxfun?

Comment: @user3374479 `bsxfun(@times,x,another_vector(:))`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't just litteraly translate a for loop in a vectorisation

When you do

```
vector : n
```

In fact, MATLAB do

```
vector(1):n
```

That's where your vectorisation is wrong.

Comment: sorry but I don't get you, where do you see me doing that?

Comment: @user3374479 by `vector` he means `(0:b-1)`

Comment: how should I proceed instead?

Answer (score 1):

say `b=10`, and assuming 'a' can be a scalar, `(k*a) = 3`;

```
x(:,1:10) = y( (0:10-1) * 3 : (0:10-1) * 3);
```

no matter what 'y' equals, the right side of the equation is a scalar, and since you aren't looping through you would simply be replacing the first 10 values of 'x' by the same number:

for example, `x(:,1:10) = 116   116   116   116   116   116   116   116   116   116`

*you cannot index iteratively without looping*

Comment: thank you for your explanation, 
@Divakar's bsxfun line did the trick :)